# How to solve Array IndexOutOfBoundException in Android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have 5 lists of years and 5 lists of amounts corresponding to year lists.

```
year_Earnings = [2011,2012,2013];
year_Expense = [2011,2012];
year_Investment = [2013];
year_Returns=[];
year_Savings=[2011,2012,2013];


amount_Earnings = [10,20,7];
amount_Expense = [5,10];
amount_Investment = [5];
amount_Returns=[];
amount_Savings=[5,10,7];
```

obviously i will get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException when i try to iterate all the lists in a single for loop.  so i  converted this all lists in to hash maps with key value pairs by using below code

```
 Map<Double, Double> earningsMap = listToMap(year_Earnings, amount_Earnings);
     Map<Double, Double> expensesMap = listToMap(year_Expense, amount_Expense);
     Map<Double, Double> investmentMap = listToMap(year_Investment, amount_Investment);
     Map<Double, Double> returnsMap = listToMap(year_Returns, amount_Returns);
     Map<Double, Double> savingsMap = listToMap(year_Savings, amount_Savings);



public Map<Double, Double> listToMap(List<Double> years, List<Double> money) {
    Map<Double, Double> newMap = new HashMap<Double, Double>();
    if (years == null || money == null || years.size() != money.size()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    for (int i=0; i< years.size(); i++ ) {
        newMap.put(years.get(i), money.get(i));
    }

    return newMap;
}
```

now i want list like below

```
year_Earnings = [2011,2012,2013];
year_Expense = [2011,2012,2013];
year_Investment = [2011,2012,2013];
year_Returns=[2011,2012,2013];
year_Savings=[2011,2012,2013];


amount_Earnings = [10,20,7];
amount_Expense = [5,10,0];
amount_Investment = [0,0,5];
amount_Returns=[0,0,0];
amount_Savings=[5,10,7];
```

can anyone please help me in doing this stuff.. thank u in advance

Comment: What's the problem in that? Did you go through the Javadoc of `java.util.Map`? You will get the methods that will provide you with what you want.

Comment: Why would you "obviously" get an arrayindexoutofboundsexception when you loop through them? Just make a for(Object object : objectList) loop that loops through all the objects in the list.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You have lists. That's what you want. But you're tranforming them into maps? You should use objects (having a year and an amount fields) instead of parallel lists like you're doing.

Comment: Where is the exception being thrown?

Comment: Your question is not clear. As much I can understand is you are having 5 year lists with each three element 2011,2012,2013 and 5 amount list with 3 element .if element is not present at given index then default value would be 0.

Comment: yes i have 5 year list, in earning yearlist i have values 2011,2012,2013 and in investment list i have only one year value that is 2013, i want all the year list look alike and the amount list values should be added zero at that position

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without any additional data structure, using the following utility method:

```
public static int[] values(int[] arr, int[] years, int firstYear, int lastYear) {
        int[] res = new int[lastYear-firstYear+1];
        int arrPos = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
            int year = firstYear + i;
            if (arrPos==arr.length || years[arrPos] >  year)
                res[i] = 0;
            else
                res[i] = arr[arrPos++];
        }
        return res;
    }
```

The input array `arr` can have any number of gaps, and the output will be an array corresponding to consecutive years, from firstYear to lastYear.

It requires that you first find the minimum and maximum year value in all year arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having such complicate and robust architecture i suggest you to work on it.

Enum that store the types of transaction

```
public enum FinancialType {
 EARNING,
 EXPENSE,
 INVESTMENT,
 RETURN,
 SAVING;
}
```

Class that will store the

```
public class FinancialOperation {
  private final FinancialType type;
  private final int year;
  private final BigDecimal value;
}
```

The util method that will transform then lists into structure.

```
    private List<FinancialOperation> createFinancialOperation(FinancialType type, List<Double> years, List<Double> money) {

     List<FinancialOperation> result = new ArrayList<>();

     for(int i = 0; i < years.size(); i++) {

        Double year = years.get(i);
        Double money = moneys.get(i);

        if(year == null) {
           continue; //or throw
        }

        BigDecimal amount = BigDecimal.ZERO;

        if(money != null) {
          amount = new BigDecimal(money,MathContext.DECIMAL128);
        }

        result.add(new FinancialOperation(type,year.intValue(),amount);
     }

     return result;

}
```

The usage is quite simple to imagine.

```
List<FinancialOperation> earningsList =  createFinancialOperation(FinancialType.EARNING,year_Earnings, amount_Earnings);
List<FinancialOperation> investmentList =  createFinancialOperation(FinancialType.INVESTMENT,year_Investment, amount_Investment);
```

and

```
Map<FinancialType,List<FinancialOperation>> map = new HashMap<>();

  map.put(FinancialType.EARNING,earningsList);
  map.put(FinancialType.INVESTMENT,investmentList);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have 5 lists of years and 5 lists of amounts corresponding to year
>   lists.

=> **This is bad solution** because if you follow this then you have to manage 10 lists, Instead I would suggest you to create Only Single `ArrayList<Object>`, every item will be of Object type.

1) Define one class Earnings with getter/setter methods.

```
public class Earning {

    int year;
    int amount;

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(int amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
}
```

2) Define `ArrayList<Earning>` type, create object of Earnings type whenever you want and put it inside the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException** excepts because your lists are of different size... Use the same size in all lists, and this error will dissapear...